# In python how do I access an ASP webpage using Requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, asp.net-mvc-3, python-requests

I have an ASP website that I'm trying to access thru Python Requests. I can get a 200 status code when access the root server directory, but when I try and access .ASP website I'm getting a 404 error. Ive tried POST as well, same result

When I access http://hostname/Scripts/Home.asp thru the webbrowser, it works fine

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post(url="http://hostname")
>>> r.statuscode
200
>>>
```

But when I try:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post(url="http://hostname/Scripts/Home.asp")
>>> r.status_code
404
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing specific to ASP pages. You might [miss POST parameters](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) or should provide [specific headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers), like `User-Agent`. Make the request manually in the browser and, using browser developer tools, observe what parameters and headers are send with the HTTP request.

Working example (using this [simple form](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/showasp.asp?filename=demo_simpleform)):

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://www.w3schools.com/asp/demo_simpleform.asp"
>>> data = {"fname": "test"}
>>> requests.post(url, data=data).status_code
200
```

Comment: Hi Just tried adding in all the header parameters and still get the 404. I did notice that the server is coming back with Apache/2.0.63 and inside the web browser its mentioned Microsoft-IIS/7.5. I'm guessing I'm calling the Apache webserver instead of Microsoft IIS server where the ASP is hosted. Are you available to chat about it